# Raspberry pi error while String piped to minimodem in python

Tags: raspbian, python

I have a raspberry pi 3 running a python script that eventually ends up with a string of characters.

How can I pipe them to [`minimodem`](http://www.whence.com/minimodem/) so I can transmit them?

minimodem starts transmitting with: `minimodem --TX 300`

I have this code :

```
if key_pressed==0 and key!=0:
    message_string = ''.join(message)
    print(message_string)
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(["minimodem" , "--tx" , "300"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    p1.stdin.write(message_string)
```

And I get this error :

> File "./Documents/Examples/texting.py", line 145, in main
>       p1.stdin.write(message_string)
>   TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Sometimes it works and some times doesn't.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with the Raspberry Pi.  What problem are you having?  What error message are you getting?

Comment: i don't get an error message, it is just that there are times that is works ! and times that it doesn't. if the sting has more that 10 characters inside i will not hear a single bip from my raspberry pi. and if it goes an plays. it freezes there when everything is finished. my python level is almost ground, and don't know from where to start trouble shooting, while everything could be wrong. how can someone pipe the content of a string to minimodem in python, and how can i now that that finished so i can continue with my code.